# Django 3.1 bug: Reflexive Many-to-many relations. Add creates two relationships instead of one

Tags: django, django-models

in the model called `Business`:

```
sold_at_businesses = models.ManyToManyField('self', db_table='businesses_to_sold_at_businesses', related_name='businesses_selling')
```

test code -  ms is a `Business` instance.

```
    ms.sold_at_businesses.clear()
    b = Business.objects.get(slug="test-business")
    if b:
        ms.sold_at_businesses.add(b)
```

Bug:
This single add call adds two entries to the pivot table. `ms -> b`  and `b -> ms`

screenshot of `businesses_to_sold_at_businesses` table after a single `.add` call:

[image]

Why are two connections being created when I clearly specify only one? this seems like a reflexive model bug in Django.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The bug was in my head:

added `symmetrical=False` in the `sold_at_business` definition in the model. Solved it.